# Python Pandas Creating a Copy of a String column but setting the new column to integers

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change string information to a new integer column.

I would like tried this type of solution below:

```
department_str department_int 
sales           1
RandD           2
tech            3
```

Thanks for the help!

I tried the pd.get_dummies which is getting some of the information I need.

Comment: `df['department_int'] = pd.factorize(df['department_str'])[0] + 1`

Comment: Just for fun, an inefficient method with `get_dummies`: `np.argmax(pd.get_dummies(df['department_str']), axis=1)`